# angular form name from inside associated controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I'm very new to angular!! What i'm trying to do is get the form name from inside the associated controller or a reference to the form object from inside the controller.

```
<form name="someName" ng-controller="formController">
    <label>Name:
        <input type="text"/>
    </label>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

controller:

```
obApp.controller('formController',function($scope){
  //this does NOT work - undefined - was expecting it to be "someName"
  var q = $scope.formName;
  //this exists - but can not use it since the 
  //name of the form can be whatever and i do not know beforehand what that name is
  var name = $scope.someName.$name;
});
```

My problem is that i don't know how in the world to get the name of the actual form. A reference to it would be even better. Looked for about 5 hours and i can't seem to figure it out.

The problem translates to this: "How to get a reference to the form object form the associated controller?".

Comment: Something like that. The idea is that i need to resolve the problem as if i do not know the form name.

Comment: There's just not enough info about the problem to know what the right way to solve it is. I'm almost positive that this is an X/Y problem.

Comment: How can there not be enough info? It's a generic problem. Any solution would do!

Comment: Because there are 3 ways I can think of to solve it and all of them are awkward. It's a generic problem with a very specific use-case that I wonder if is valid. Anyway, Josep gave you the least awkward answer.

Comment: There is rarely a reason you would ever need to do this; therefore this seems to be an X/Y problem.  That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.  Providing a bit more context about the reason you need to access the form name instead of asking why you can't will be more helpful.

Comment: Ok, now i see what you guys ment by x/y problem. Will rephrase the question. Thanx.

Comment: I figured out the answer to my original X question in the meantime. Thank you for your help guys - it made me think about the original problem in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you want to access the DOM element of the controller, you could do it like this:

```
obApp.controller('formController',function($scope, $element){
  var name = $element.attr('name');
});
```

But that is considered a bad practice, you shouldn't be accessing the DOM element directly inside the controller, consider using a directive instead.

Comment: Yeah, i wrote this myself in another controller, but it seems that i'm too tired right now to even think properly. Will not mark as accepted since i realised, by seeing the above comments that i was approaching this problem in the wrong way. Thumbed up though.

Comment: I actually dug a little deeper and found the answer to my X problem - will mark as accepted since i don't need to rephrase my original question and this answers the original question.